# Passing button value from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass button value from modal to input value on main window.

```js
$('#pickCustomer').click(function() {
  var id = $("#customerID").val();
  var name = $("#pickCustomer").val();
  $("#kodep").val(id);
  $("#namap").val(name);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:32%;min-height:400px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;float:left;padding:1%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="kodep" name="kodep" type="hidden" value="">
        <input style="float:left;width:75%;margin-right:7px;" id="namap" name="namap" type="text" value="">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customertable">Search</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


<div style="width:80%;left:30%;display:none;" id="customertable" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="tablehasil" class="display" style="width:100%;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Customer ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Telp</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1001<input id="customerID" type="hidden" value="1001"></td>
              <td><button id "pickCustomer" style="background:none;border:none;font-size:13px;" value="test" data-dismiss="modal">testing</button></td>
              <td>USA</td>
              <td>0000000000</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I click the search button, a modal popup appears, there is a list of subscribers, I use dataTable js to sort it.

When I click the button (customer name) that is in the modal popup, the input name is not filled by the value I want, and i don't see any error on chrome console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing some HTML elements inside a PHP loop and you're setting the same IDs (`customerID` and `pickCustomer`) to multiple elements. IDs are meant to be unique. A quick fix will be to use class names instead of IDs, here is an example:

```
<?php
    $sqlpeg="select * from customer_table";
    $qpeg=mysql_query($sqlpeg);
    while($aspeg=mysql_fetch_assoc($qpeg)){
        echo'
            <tr>
                <td>'.$aspeg["customer_id"].'<input class="customerID" type="hidden" value="'.$aspeg["customer_id"].'"></td>
                <td><button class="pickCustomer" style="background:none;border:none;font-size:13px;" value="'.$aspeg["customer_name"].'" data-dismiss="modal">'.$aspeg["nama"].'</button></td>
                <td>'.$aspeg["address"].'</td>
                <td>'.$aspeg["telp"].'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
?>

<script>
    $('.pickCustomer').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents("tr").find(".customerID").val();
        var name = $(this).val();
        $("#kodep").val(id);
        $("#namap").val(name);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mention about duplicated id's. and i change as you suggest. but still, as mentioned on Andrew Halpern answer, missing equals sign on class"pickCustomer"

Comment: @Gumilar I didn't notice that. I've edited my answer to add the missing `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you're missing equals sign in `<button id"pickCustomer"`...
This should be `<button id="pickCustomer"`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes i forgot equals sign. and Titus answer mention about duplicated id is also solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Please try using class in your button an input element as in the following.

```
 <td>'.$aspeg["customer_id"].'<input class="customerID" type="hidden" value="'.$aspeg["customer_id"].'"></td>
                <td><button class="pickCustomer" style="background:none;border:none;font-size:13px;" value="'.$aspeg["customer_name"].'" data-dismiss="modal">'.$aspeg["nama"].'</button></td>
                <td>'.$aspeg["address"].'</td>
                <td>'.$aspeg["telp"].'</td>
```

Also in the jquery section of your code try making the following changes.

```
  $('.pickCustomer').click(function() {
          var id=$(this).prev().val();
          var name=$(this).val();
          $("#kodep").val(id);
          $("#namap").val(name);
    });
```

It will select the currently clicked(using this) element that is the button with class pickCustomer, it will then get the value of it's immediately preceding element that is the input and assign it to id variable. Since you were using id instead of class I think that the browser was only selecting the first matching id and ignoring the rest. Hope it helps.